# Needs to close model window after open CSV file through IFRAME

Tags: javascript, html

I've a HTML model window, which has a `IFrame` and load a `CSV` file at run time. It gives open/save option whenever open the csv file.

If I click open the `CSV` file was opened in Excel,but HTML page still open at the background.  How can I close this window automatically after open `CSV`?

Note :: I've MS Office 2007 is installed in my machine

Comment: Provide a code snippet and we will be able to help. I've also marked this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393862/how-can-i-close-the-html-model-screen-automatically

Comment: But I didn't get solution for that question also.

Comment: That's because your question is unclear in both cases. You are fundamentally asking exactly the same question here because you did not receive an answer on the other post. Try revising your earlier question and adding some code examples. Also explain why you are trying to achieve the effect you are asking for. In most cases, it seems that other respondents don't see a point in doing what you are doing which would suggest your approach needs revision.